# Matching input String pattern with a given string and separating w.r.t special characters

Tags: java, string

I have a piece of data in the following formats/patterns :

```
    String inputFruit = "[Apple,Banana(Mango-Juice,lemon-Pickle,Grape-Drinks)]";
    String inputFruit = "Apple,Banana(Mango-Juice,lemon-Pickle,Grape-Drinks)"
    String inputFruit = "Apple(Mango-Juice,lemon-Pickle,Grape-Drinks)Banana"
```

Now I have to extract and store individual datas like :

```
firstFruit  = Apple
secondFruit = Banana
miscFruit  = Mango-Juice,lemon-Pickle,Grape-Drinks
```

I have the following code snippet which I am using :

```
    public static void splitFruits(String inputFruit)
    {
        String firstFruit = StringUtils.EMPTY;
        String secondFruit = StringUtils.EMPTY;
        String miscFruit = StringUtils.EMPTY;

        inputFruit = inputFruit.replaceAll("\\[" , "");
        inputFruit = inputFruit.replaceAll("\\]" , "");

        String frts[] = inputFruit.split("\\("");
        String frtp[] = frts[0].split(",");

        firstFruit = frtp[0];
        secondFruit = frtp[1];
        miscFruit = frts[1];



    }
```

Here I need to store Apple in variable firstFruit, Banana in secondFruit, and whatever is there inside () in miscFruit.

My code is able to extract value for a specific patter mentioned in no 1.How can I create pattern match statements to match with input values in all the above specified 3 different formats and store them separately.

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: Language used is JAVA .

Comment: With my method I will be able to extract the values as I did. But at run-time I do not know the in put string pattern , so I need to create a match and then extract values. Please help me understand how I will be able to do so ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `frts[0]` to get the first and second fruits, combine `frts[0]` and `frts[2]` (that is, the parts on either side of the parenthetical section) and split that.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer as I do understand what you are trying to say but my actual problem is :

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer as I do understand what you are trying to say but my actual problem is : With my method I will be able to extract the values as I did. But at run-time I do not know the in put string pattern , so I need to create a match and then extract values. Please help me understand how I will be able to do so ?

Comment: I did.  For all of the examples you gave, `frts` should have 3 elements: what is before the open parenthesis, what is between parentheses, and what is after the closing parenthesis.  The middle element has your `miscFruit`; the other two have, between them, the first and second fruits.